# Toggle flashlight in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Can anyone say how to toggle flashlight in Windows Phone 8.1 using C#? It seems like there are lots of API changes in Windows Phone 8.1 and most of the API's in WP 8.0 are not supported. Answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm able to use [TorchControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.torchcontrol.aspx) on my Lumia 820 like this - first you have to specify which camera you will use - the default is front (I think that's why you may find some problems) and we want the back one - the one with flash light. Sample code:

```
// edit - I forgot to show GetCameraID:
private static async Task<DeviceInformation> GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel desiredCamera)
{
    DeviceInformation deviceID = (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture))
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.EnclosureLocation != null && x.EnclosureLocation.Panel == desiredCamera);

    if (deviceID != null) return deviceID;
    else throw new Exception(string.Format("Camera of type {0} doesn't exist.", desiredCamera));
}

// init camera
async private void InitCameraBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cameraID = await GetCameraID(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.Panel.Back);
    captureManager = new MediaCapture();

    await captureManager.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video,
            PhotoCaptureSource = PhotoCaptureSource.VideoPreview,
            AudioDeviceId = string.Empty,
            VideoDeviceId = cameraID.Id
        });
}

// then to turn on/off camera
var torch = captureManager.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
if (torch.Supported) torch.Enabled = true;

// turn off
if (torch.Supported) torch.Enabled = false;
```

Note that it's a good idea to call `captureManager.Dispose()` after you finish with it.

---

Note also that on some phones to turn on torch/flashlight you will need to start preview first.

Comment: Its working fine, but it often crashes and slow in turning on the flashlight. What's the problem?

Comment: @BalasubramaniM It may depend where you have put that code, what's the exception? Especially don't forget to Dispose() resources when you finish it - I've encountered some crashes/hangs when preview/camera wasn't disposed/closed.

Comment: No, app is getting crashed. For the first time, it works perfectly. But for the second time, while coming to InitializeAsync(), app getting crashed. Even I used captureManager.Dispose() function. Don't know whats the problem.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM I think there is a big chance that the problem occurs because the camera wasn't properly released - that's probably why you can't initialize it once again. It's hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: Code is very simple. I am disposing the camera while turning off the flashlight. That's it. One more thing to note, I couldn't able to turn on flashlight or even camera in my phone after using any application. Camera and Flashlight works only after restarting the application.

Comment: @BalasubramaniM Hmm, then there must be something wrong with your code. Maybe the problem is that you try to `Dispose()` just right away after turning torch off, and it may need some time and the resources are not freed. Do a simple test: provide four buttons: one for initialize, second turn on torch, third turn off, fourth dispose. As I've tried it's working nice.

Comment: Doesn't work on Lumia 930 (8.1) despite TorchControl is supported.

Comment: It did worked in my C# application, now trying the JS version.

Answer (score 4):

[`Windows Phone 8.1`](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Using_the_camera_light_in_Windows_Phone_7,_8_and_8.1) is the first version with a dedicated API for controlling the camera light. This API stems from Windows 8.1 but is usable in Windows Phone 8.1 projects and in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 projects.

```
var mediaDev = new MediaCapture();
await mediaDev.InitializeAsync();
var videoDev = mediaDev.VideoDeviceController;
var tc = videoDev.TorchControl;
if (tc.Supported)
   {
   if (tc.PowerSupported)
      tc.PowerPercent = 100;
   tc.Enabled = true;
   }
```

**Note:**
Note: TorchControl.Supported returns false on most phones in WP8.1 developer preview. It is expected to be fixed by a firmware update by the time WP 8.1 is released. Tested Phones at the time of writing: Lumia 620, 822, 1020: not working, Lumia 1520: working.

Comment: Nope. Its not working. It gets out after reaching if(tc.Supported). Am using Lumia 820.

Comment: check my edited answer! please mark it as answer if it has helped you

Comment: It says, Not supported.

Comment: Now getting UnAuthorizedAccessException after updated my phone today in mediaDev.InitializeAsync(); even after checking Webcam and Microphone in capabilities.

Comment: Doesn't work on Lumia 930 (8.1) despite TorchControl is supported.

Comment: On some device, you must make sure that the camera is initialized and in video mode. 
cameraCapture = new CameraCapture();
PreviewElement.Source = await cameraCapture.Initialize(CaptureUse.Video);
var tc = cameraCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl;
if (tc.Supported)
 {
 if (tc.PowerSupported)
  tc.PowerPercent = 100;
         tc.Enabled = true;
 }
And oddly enough, the video light might not work if the phone is connected with a USB cable.

Answer (score 2):

In Nokia Lumia 1520, you use **FlashControl** to toggle the flash light instead of TorchControl.

```
    //to switch OFF flash light
    mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = false;
    //to switch ON flash light
    mediacapture.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: The same problem goes for L1320 too. And this solved my problem thanks. But it seems to be better to set both FlashControl and TorchControl.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work on my Lumia 1520. You need to start video recording to get flashlight working:

```
        var videoEncodingProperties = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Vga);

        var videoStorageFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("tempVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        await captureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(videoEncodingProperties, videoStorageFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my Lumia 1520. I need to start video recording and start preview to get flashlight working:

```
await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync();
```