# WindowsPhone 8.1 FlashLight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have Nokia 730 and I want to make FlashLight work on it. But next code crash:

```
     MediaCapture mc = new MediaCapture();
        await mc.InitializeAsync();

            if (mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Supported == true)
            {
                mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
                mc.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.PowerPercent = 100; // here is crash
            }
```

Any ideas? For some reasons solutions with older platforms (wp 7, wp8) doesn't works at all.

Comment: What means "code crashes"? Is there some exception? If yes, which?

Comment: PowerPercent  not supported

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toggle flashlight in Windows Phone 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847510/toggle-flashlight-in-windows-phone-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by next code:

```
        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize Media Capture and Settings Objects, mediaCapture declared global outside this method 
        var mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();

        // Grab all available VideoCapture Devices and find rear device (usually has flash)
        await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

        var videoEncodingProperties = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Vga);

        var videoStorageFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync("tempVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(videoEncodingProperties, videoStorageFile);

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
        mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
    }
```

But for some reason I should wait 500 milliseconds before enable TorchControl. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847510/toggle-flashlight-in-windows-phone-8-1) it could help to try the following:

```
//to switch OFF flash light
mc.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = false;
//to switch ON flash light
mc.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Doesn't works.... tried also:
            _mediaDev.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Auto = false;
            _mediaDev.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.AssistantLightEnabled = true;
            _mediaDev.VideoDeviceController.FlashControl.Enabled = true;